# What adjective to use to refer to the number of people who inhabit an apartment?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I thought you could say something like this:

> We were having dinner in our three-people apartment.

(*We* are the three people who live in the apartment.)

But Google doesn't yield results for *three-people apartment*.

What's the correct way of saying it?

Comment: Three-person apartment? We don't usually pluralize the noun in [compound adjectives](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm).

Comment: And I probably would've used "'in' our three-person apartment," if I had only been intending to indicate the location of our dinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to summarize the answers given so far.

The more important point: in English, We don't usually pluralize the noun in [compound adjectives](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adjectives_compound_adjectives.htm).  So

- six-foot ruler
- [Three-Dog Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Dog_Night)
- four-door car.

Less important, in most English-speaking countries, housing units are characterized by the number of bedrooms they have: it's a three-bedroom apartment, a four-bedroom house.  How many people you put in each bedroom is up to you.

Auditoriums and vehicles of land and air are characterized by the number of seats they have -- a two-seat sports-car, a 100-seat jet, a thousand-seat theater -- even though you can only put one person in a seat.

Only tasks, small watercraft, and for some reason tents are characterized by the number of people they hold: a one-person job, a three-man canoe, a two-person pup-tent.

Answer (score 0):

You can say "We were having dinner at our apartment. We live there on a triple sharing basis" or "We were having dinner at our triple room in the apartment".

Comment: Neither "triple sharing basis" or "triple room" is something that this US English speaker would understand.

Comment: This BritEnglish thinks "having dinner at our triple room" means the three of you share a bedroom and were eating your dinner there. Watch out for the crumbs!

Answer (score 0):

**The three of us are having a dinner party at our apartment.**

"Three-person" might be correct, but I would not expect to hear this as an expression in normal conversation. "Three-person IVF" is the only time I've ever heard it used.

In NAm, we say things like, "Our apartment is a 3-bed(room), 2 bath."